# UILocalNotification and region monitoring

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, geofencing, clregion

I am rolling a notification service into an existing app that requires geofenced notifications. CLRegion looks like how you are supposed to do this, a la the Apple way. However, they limit you to 20 regions that can be monitored by a single application. There are definitely going to need to be 20+ notification regions that are provided. On the one hand, I could just monitor location myself and fire notifications when they enter that region. Obviously the app would need to be open for this to occur. Can I use CLLocationManager when the app is in the background? Is there a workaround to having more than twenty regions being monitored? Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a nice post about enabling location updates in iOS on the background:

[Using CoreLocation](http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/)

Also here an answer with a work around for adding more than 20 geofence regions:

[Adding more than 20 geofence regions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29703957/4700871)

Hope this helps.