# How to monitor more than 20 regions using CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

I have about 2000 regions I want to monitor (entrance only) using `CLLocationManager`, I have a function that finds the 20 nearest stores (`Store` is a class that inherits from `NSObject` and has a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` property named `geoPoint`) to the user's current location but where should I call it?

If someone will be able to help me with a code example it'll be great!

Finding the 20 nearest stores func:

```
-(void)sortClosestStores
{
    [self.allStores sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
    CLLocation *location1=[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:((Store*)obj1).geoPoint.latitude longitude:((Store*)obj1).geoPoint.longitude];
    CLLocation *location2=[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:((Store*)obj2).geoPoint.latitude longitude:((Store*)obj2).geoPoint.longitude];

    float dist1 =[location1 distanceFromLocation:self.locationManager.location];
    float dist2 = [location2 distanceFromLocation:self.locationManager.location];
    if (dist1 == dist2) {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
    else if (dist1 < dist2) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
}];

    if (self.twentyClosestStores==nil) {
        self.twentyClosestStores=[NSMutableArray array];
    }

    if (self.previousTwentyStores==nil) {
        self.previousTwentyStores=[NSMutableArray array];
    }
    self.previousTwentyStores=self.twentyClosestStores;
    self.twentyClosestStores=[NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        [self.twentyClosestStores addObject:[self.allStores objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to know when the device enters a store?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654154/need-to-get-more-than-20-notification-for-region-monitoring).  There are other similar questions on SO that have more code too, but I couldn't find them immediately with a quick search.

Comment: @EricGalluzzo I've tried it but I couldn't understand, that's why I need a code here.

Comment: What is significant location updates at all? And how is it different from the regular location updates.